# Properties how to use in spring xml

Tags: spring, properties

`<context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/classes/config.config"/>
config.config:
path=com`

`<import resource="../../conf/${path}/test.xml"/>`

> error：
>    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [test.service.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'path'
>   at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'path'
>   at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)

${path} can`t use in import,how to do ??

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem - do you managed to solve this? Note that it works if you import file1.xml for example and in file1.xml you have another <import resource="${something}.xml"/>

Comment: the indirect import doesn't always work :P

Comment: my workaround is to System.setProperty(...) before context creation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do with this way?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:yourpropertiesfile"></property>
</bean>
```

It is possible to put your properties in other location? Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @zhizhu2012 is not a xml properties file, is a spring configuration file that I put before. Can you try to put your file in your classpath? My files are in a mvn project with a standard layout (src, src/main/java, src/main/resources...) and it works.